# Filter multiple Urls from a file text

Tags: curl

I have a list of URLs in file urls.txt.

If possible, I want to get all URLs that give a 404 error when I attempt to fetch them with `curl`, and copy them to a new file.

For example the URLs in my file urls.txt:

```
mysite.com/page1
mysite.com/page2
mysite.com/page3
mysite.com/page4
mysite.com/page5
...
mysite.com/page100
...
mysite.com/page1000
```

so I want to try to fetch each one and if the fetching fails with error 404, I want to store the failing URL into a new file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the best, but try this:

Make a file `urlcheck.sh`, then give permission to execute. or simply enter this command:

```bsh
touch urlcheck.sh
chmod +x urlcheck.sh
```

Paste below script to `urlcheck.sh`

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
TIMEOUT=3

if [ ! -f output404.txt ]; then
    touch output404.txt
fi

while IFS= read -r line; do
    OUT_URL=$(curl -I $line 2>&1 -m $TIMEOUT| awk '/HTTP\// {print $2}')
    if [ "$OUT_URL" == "404" ]; then
        echo $line >> output404.txt
        echo "$line written to output404.txt"
    else
        echo "$line     $OUT_URL"
    fi
done < "$1"
```

and save.

To run the script:

```
./urlcheck.sh urls.txt
```

then, check `output404.txt` generated by the script.

**Please note** that The url in each line must an url readable by `curl` such as `https://unix.stackexchange.com/`.

you can change the timeout second in line `TIMEOUT=3`.

Comment: thank sir, but output404.txt not generate after runing script

Comment: then create it first `touch output404.txt`. I have modified the script. please check. let me know if it works

Comment: the fil output 404.txt generate  is still empty

Comment: sorry, my bad, I forgot to rename `404.txt` to `output404.txt`. fixed now. try it

Comment: Thank very much sir, now is working, thank a lot

Comment: Glad it's working. You can still improve the performance if you edit the `curl` command.

Comment: can i change "404" to other word like "404 Not found" or "error"  or "Not found"  i tried but not found

Comment: you have to change the curl command too for that. the current curl command only output response header, not searching the whole page text. It will affect the performance